# Why does Stack Exchange use the Microsoft stack?

Tags: discussion

Why was Stack Exchange implemented using the closed source, proprietary Microsoft stack instead of free and open source software (FOSS)?

Comment: The .NET framework isn't closed source.

Comment: Isn't closed source anymore* :D

Comment: Although, it still isn't completely open sourced...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We use Redis, HaProxy and numerous Linux boxen on the backend. There's FOSS in them there infrastructure!

Our main stack for the sites is indeed the MS stack - that's what the founders started off with (probably due to the respective backgrounds of the founders plus the existence of [bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/)).

We are now deeply invested in the platform - changing it for the sake of changing it makes no sense.